# Count where value is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this SELECT. And I want to count (or sum?) Yellow and Red card of players (Count Yellow cards only where YellowCard = 1, and Count Red cards only where RedCard = 1).. This SELECT does not work correctly. It count card even if there are 0 or NULL.. How can i correct it?

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, COUNT(YellowCard) AS Yellow, COUNT(RedCard) AS Red, Team.Name 
FROM PlayerMatch 
Inner join Player On PlayerMatch.PlayerId = Player.PlayerId 
INNER JOIN Team ON Player.TeamId = Team.TeamId 
INNER JOIN Match ON PlayerMatch.MatchId = Match.MatchId 
WHERE(YellowCard = 1 OR RedCard = 1) 
GROUP BY Lastname, Firstname, Name 
ORDER BY Yellow DESC
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname,
       SUM(YellowCard) AS Yellow, SUM(RedCard) AS Red, t.Name 
FROM PlayerMatch pm Inner join
     Player p
     On pm.PlayerId = p.PlayerId INNER JOIN
     Team t
     ON p.TeamId = t.TeamId INNER JOIN
     Match m
     ON pm.MatchId = m.MatchId 
WHERE (YellowCard = 1 OR RedCard = 1) 
GROUP BY Lastname, Firstname, Name
ORDER BY Yellow DESC;
```

This assumes that the values of `YellowCard` and `RedCard` are always 0 or 1 (or `NULL`).  That seems like a reasonable assumption.

If that is not the case, then use `CASE`:

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YellowCard = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yellow,
       SUM(CASE WHEN RedCard = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red,
       t.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `NULL`s are not counted. If `YellowCard`, `RedCard` take only `0,1,NULL` values:

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, COUNT(nullif(YellowCard,0)) AS Yellow, COUNT(nullif(RedCard,0)) AS Red, Team.Name 
FROM PlayerMatch 
Inner join Player On PlayerMatch.PlayerId = Player.PlayerId 
INNER JOIN Team ON Player.TeamId = Team.TeamId 
INNER JOIN Match ON PlayerMatch.MatchId = Match.MatchId 
WHERE(YellowCard = 1 OR RedCard = 1) 
GROUP BY Lastname, Firstname, Name 
ORDER BY Yellow DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because in SQL that will start from group & where clause, so your alias doesn't exist yet.

you have to use SQL subquery as this tutorial : http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery

That would work if u try : 
SELECT * 
FROM PlayerMatch Inner join...
WHERE YellowCard in (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE YellowCard = 1)
AND RedCard in (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE RedCard = 1)...